# SQL query with date filter with 14 day interval

Tags: sql, intervals

I am trying to filter `payroll dates` where the result will show me '2011-12-25' plus every 14 days after that `up until today`.

The query I have is:

```
 SELECT trxbegdt FROM UPR30300
    WHERE TRXBEGDT <= getdate() and trxbegdt >= DATEADD( DAY ,14, '2011-12-25')
    group by trxbegdt
    order by TRXBEGDT desc
```

The problem I am having is that the results show dates that are outside of the 14 day intervals which aren't normal payroll transaction begin dates. Would anyone have a solution to comply my conditions?

Comment: Which dates do you want to include? The dates `'2011-12-25' + 14 days`, `'2011-12-25' + 28 days`, `'2011-12-25' + 42 days`, etc.?

Comment: +1 for the interesting question @Jae Chang :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hows this? This uses a recursive CTE to create the list of valid payroll dates, and then joins that to the real table...

```
WITH PayrollDates AS
(
  SELECT CONVERT(datetime,'2011-12-25') AS PayrollDate
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(DAY,14,PayrollDate) AS PayrollDate
  FROM PayrollDates
  WHERE DATEADD(DAY,14,PayrollDate) <= GETDATE()
)
SELECT 
  UPR30300.trxbegdt 
FROM UPR30300
INNER JOIN PayrollDates
ON UPR30300.trxbegdt = PayrollDates.PayrollDate
```

Comment: That didn't work when I tried it on my copy of SQL (MS SQL 2012): `Invalid column name 'LastDate'`.  But it worked perfectly when I changed the ON clause to `ON UPR30300.trxbegdt >= PayrollDates.PayrollDate AND UPR30300.trxbegdt < DATEADD(DAY,14,PayrollDates.PayrollDate)`

Comment: Actually it looks like the OP wants only dates that fall exactly on the 14 day intervals.  That is an even easier change to the ON clause: `ON UPR30300.trxbegdt = PayrollDates.PayrollDate`

Comment: @EvilBob22, thanks for the catch.  Had a typo in my query.  Fixed now.

Comment: You guys are awesome! May I ask what kind of function or type of query the "WITH PayrollDates AS" is? I've never seen that type of query start. Thank you!

Comment: @JaeChang the "WITH PayrollDates AS" is the beginning of a Common Table Expression (CTE).  CTE's are a powerful way to define a subquery (or virtual table) prior to the query from which it is consumed.  CTEs also have the unique capability of being recursive, and I am using that ability in this query to recursively add 14 days to the previous PayrollDate until we reach today's date.  You can read more about recurseive CTEs here: http://aka.ms/hjj55s

Answer (score 0):

<strike>SELECT trxbegdt FROM UPR30300 as a
        where trxbegdt + interval 14 day = b.trxbegdt
        (SELECT trxbegdt FROM UPR30300
            WHERE TRXBEGDT <= sysdate() and trxbegdt >= '2011-12-25' )
        As b
        order by TRXBEGDT desc</strike>

You may use few variations to get the rolling dates with this constant interval.
E.g.

- `Datediff(day,a.trxbegdt,b.trxbegdt) = 14`
- `dateadd(b.trxbegdt,14,day)= a.trbegdt`

<strike>PS: it is super painful to format answers in mobile. plus the code is logic based so run at your end to view results and comment for further updates please.</strike>

- ## ALTERNATIVE ANSWER using a nested query that generates dates list with constant interval.

  - [SQLFIDDLE Demonstration for MYSQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e031/5)

**Query to generate dates list between today and your specified date with constant interval of 14 days**

```
set @i:= 0;

SELECT date_format(DATE(ADDDATE('2012-10-05', 
INTERVAL @i:=@i+14 DAY)),'%Y-%m-%d')
AS dateP, @i
FROM payroll
HAVING @i < datediff(now(), date '2012-10-05')
;
```

**Above query Output**

```
DATEP         @IntervalDays
2012-10-19    14
2012-11-02    28
2012-11-16    42
2012-11-30    56
2012-12-14    70
```

**Final query that is *Supposed* to fetch records**

```
set @i:= 0;

SELECT distinct datestamp FROM payroll
WHERE date(datestamp) in (
SELECT DATE(ADDDATE('2012-10-05', 
INTERVAL @i:=@i+14 DAY) ) AS dateP
FROM payroll
where @i < DATEDIFF(now(), date '2012-10-05') 
)
;
```

*However due to some MYSQL engine behaviour* it's not fetching the records, with such ignorane to date comparison. So I guess for now, you are better off with above answer. I wanted to update this post with the info for the very fact of sharing knowledge.

Feel free to comment :)

---

- ### Updating after above mentioned variable scope is resolved.

As for the findings, **in local machines with mysql installed works well** for above query by replacing `in` clause with `inner join`. However it still doesn't do in SQLFIDDLE. So the workaround is to delcare variable within nested `select` query. Further `IN` clause doesn't seem to work well either. Anyway, `inner join` outperforms `in` clause. So final solution is as followed. :)

- [reference for SQL Demonstration](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/80dff/1) - updated.

Query:

```
select p.id, p.datestamp, s.datep from
Payroll as p
inner join 
(
SELECT DATE(DATE_ADD('2012-10-05', 
INTERVAL @i:=@i+14 DAY) ) AS dateP
FROM Payroll, (SELECT @i:=0) r
where @i < DATEDIFF(now(), date '2012-10-05') 
) as s 
on p.datestamp = s.dateP
;
```

Results:

```
ID  DATESTAMP                           DATEP
7   October, 19 2012 00:00:00+0000      October, 19 2012 00:00:00+0000
8   November, 02 2012 00:00:00+0000     November, 02 2012 00:00:00+0000
10  November, 16 2012 00:00:00+0000     November, 16 2012 00:00:00+0000
12  November, 30 2012 00:00:00+0000     November, 30 2012 00:00:00+0000
```

Comment: PLeas avoid code only answers, add some explanation to the code.

Comment: @bonCodigo The "interval 14 day" portion does not work in SSMS.

Comment: @jaechang could you please adjust above query logic to yours and run it? e.g. u may use `dateadd` to replace interval above.

Comment: @JaeChang `with` doesn't support MYSQL, so you can use `with` block in `SQL Server`. Either way, it's good to have a code that is compatible with most RDBMS in anycase.